# Combining AND OR in SQL statement?

Tags: php, sql, laravel-5

Using laravel, this is some of my code in my controller file:

```
    public function postsearch(Request $request){

    $searchItem=$request['searchItem'];
    $searchLocation=$request['searchLocation'];

    $criteria=$request['criteria'];

    if($criteria == 'schools'){

    $result=schools::whereRaw("MATCH(name,describtion) AGAINST('$searchItem') AND MATCH(location) AGAINST('$searchLocation')")->where('status','')->get();

    if(count($result)>0){

    $count=count($result);

    return view('schools', array('result' => $result))->with(array('searchItem'=>$searchItem,'searchLocation'=>$searchLocation,'criteria'=>$criteria,'count'=>$count))->with('searchItem',$searchItem); 

    }

    else{

        return view('schools')->with(array('msg'=>'Oops, No result found','count'=>'0','searchItem'=>$searchItem,'searchLocation'=>$searchLocation,'criteria'=>$criteria));

    }

    }
```

This is the code that I'm trying to edit:

```
  $result=schools::whereRaw("MATCH(name,describtion) AGAINST('$searchItem') AND MATCH(location) AGAINST('$searchLocation')")->where('status','')->get();
```

If I am trying to search for a school but I just put in the school name and not the location, I get 0 results.  I have to put in the location the school is in.  But I want to make it so that the website displays the school in every location it is in if the person doesn't know the location.  Right now, I have to put in the location of the school in order for it to display in the results.

Secondly, if a school name is "Florida State University (FSU)", I would have to type in "Florida State University" to get the college to show up.  "Florida" or "FSU" would not work.  Is there a way to fix it so that items in the database show up if the search query matches up to any part of the name?

**UPDATE:**

Had to pay a guy a few bucks to come up with a code that worked:

```
        $result=schools::where('<put the variable you are searching for here>', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchItem.'%')
            ->where('location', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchLocation.'%')
            ->where('status','')->orderBy('name', 'asc')->get();
```

Comment: how about SQL LIKE Operator ??https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

Comment: So where would I put the LIKE at? MATCH () AGAINST () LIKE MATCH () AGAINST()?

Comment: whereRaw("name,describtion LIKE '$searchItem'.'%' OR location LIKE '$searchLocation'.'%' ")->where('status','')->get();

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use

Comment: i have posted a answer please try that. let me know if you need any help on that.

Comment: solution posted above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$result=schools::whereRaw("MATCH(name,describtion) AGAINST('$searchItem') OR MATCH(location) AGAINST('$searchLocation')")->where('status','')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result=schools::whereRaw("MATCH(name,describtion) 
AGAINST('$searchItem') AND MATCH(location) 
AGAINST('$searchLocation')")->where('status','')->get();
```

replace with this

```
    $result = schools::where(function ($q) use ($searchItem, $searchLocation)
                    {
                        return $q->where('name', 'LIKE', 
                         $searchItem. '%')
                          ->orWhere('description', 'LIKE', '%' . 
                                $searchItem. '%');
                            ->orWhere('location', 'LIKE', '%' . 
                                $searchLocation. '%');
                                     });
   $result->where('status','')->get();
```

Comment: ErrorException (E_NOTICE)
Use of undefined constant schools - assumed 'schools'

Comment: It worked except now the the results aren't showing.  where the schools should be seen, it's just an empty area.

Comment: Thomas lets add  description also and try check the code and make the changes

Comment: had to remove the semicolon after the first orWhere statement because there was an error that said unexpected "->"

Comment: but the  schools are still not displaying in the results area.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166075/discussion-between-arun-jai-and-thomas).

Answer (score 0):

You can change this

```
$result=schools::whereRaw("MATCH(name,describtion) 
AGAINST('$searchItem') AND MATCH(location) 
AGAINST('$searchLocation')")->where('status','')->get();
```

to

```
$result=schools::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchItem.'%')
                 ->orWhere('describtion', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchItem.'%')
                 ->orWhere('location', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchLocation.'%')
                 ->where('status','')->get();
```

I've also noticed that you've written 'describtion'. Are you sure it's not description? And also why are you checking status against an empty string?

Comment: The original code worked with "describtion".  The guy who originally made the code isn't very good at spelling common English words.

Comment: Ok this code works.  Problem is now it is showing schools that don't even match the query.  There could be a school called with "UP" or "FEU" in the name and a whole bunch of schools show up.  The school with "FEU" shows up as the 20th result in the list.

Comment: That may be because the query is also searching the same name in its description too, the descriptions might contain the terms "FEU" or "UP". And the data is ordered by its id and not relevance.

Comment: Also the query returns every data that resembles the term. For eg, the term "UP" matches with "UPWARD" or "CUP" or "CUPBOARD"

Comment: I removed the describtion code but schools are still showing in the search results.  I could search "Far" for the school "Far Eastern University" and "CENTRO ESCOLAR UNIVERSITY - MANILA" would be the first to pop-up.  (yea, these are Philippine universities).

Comment: did you search with only the name of the school or did you include the location also? If you did include the location in your search parameter then the result will also include the schools in those locations. Try once without the location, in fact remove the orwhere line for location and give it a try. If the location is creating a problem then we will change the structure of the code by adding some additional checks

Comment: I can search with just the name only and I will see schools but the school that matches my query will not be at the top.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166092/discussion-between-thomas-and-rohit-kapali).

Comment: solution posted above.